# How do I increase the number of characters accepted by MySQL?

Tags: 8, database

This is how I've defined the `content_body` in my `FieldWidget`:

```
$widget['content_body'] = array(
  '#title' => $this->t('Body text'),
  '#type' => 'textarea',
  '#default_value' => isset($items[$delta]) ? $items[$delta]->content_body : '',
);
```

which allows me to enter more than 255 characters when editing/creating the content. However, I get an error when more than 255 characters are entered and the content is created/updated.

This is the schema in my `FieldType` class:

```
$schema['columns']['content_body'] = array(
  'type' => 'text',
  'size' => 'tiny',
  'not null' => FALSE,
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use field type as  `Text (formatted, long) or Text (formatted, long, with summary)`